# Setting individual login points in minecraft (java edition) (Creative mode)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I found that previous answers aren't working. I found that they are for survival.

I want to be able to set an initial world spawn, but then be able to change where that spawn is after a player moves to their desired location for building.

```
/setspawn <x> <y> <z>
/spawnpoint <x> <y> <z>
```

The above commands do not default my player to spawn at x,y,z. After logging out and logging back in I still spawn at the world spawn point.

Comment: Can you point out what answers didn't work and what you tried?

Comment: For the VTCer: why do you think/how do you know this is a modded version of Minecraft?

Comment: @Joachim Because of the self-answer.

Comment: @pppery The close rule states that *technical* support of modded Minecraft is off-topic. This isn't very technical as it's not a crash log, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue lay in my userlogin plugin. I could change the config file at [this](https://github.com/ElCholoGamer/userlogin/blob/5461bef170933815f2ed2ea4615354025b077075/src/main/resources/config.yml#L75) location in order to change where the player logs in.